# Get Percentage of arraylist values from sum of arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

i have an array list  where i have some value  arraylist like

```
ArrayList<Integer> keyList = new ArrayList<Integer>(treeMap.keySet());
```

Values here: `*62,58,10,6*`  i am getting some if value `*136.0*`

Now what i want is to get % of each  value and print them again as an arraylist  there something like this

```
*40%,34%,16%, 10%*
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far? What's that you are looking for here? Where are you stucked?

Comment: What is the problem to divide every integer in an array to the known value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double sum = 0.0; //if you use version earlier than java-8
//double sum = IntStream.of(keyList).sum(); //if you are using java-8 
for(int i = 0 ; i < keyList.size() ; i++){
  sum += keyList.get(i);    
}
for(int i = 0 ; i < keyList.size() ; i++){
  System.out.println((keyList.get(i)/sum )*100 + "%");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In java 8, you can do it like this:

```
    ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(62, 58, 10, 6));
    double sum = arrayList.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
    arrayList.stream().forEach(i -> System.out.printf("%.2f%% ", (i / sum) * 100));
```